# Spring Task Scheduler

Tags: spring

I know about spring task scheduler works with fixed delay by using `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000)` and `@Scheduled(fixedRate=2000)` but what If I want to execute certain task after 15 minutes from know. Is there any such `Trigger` that I can use to each that functinality?
Scenario Like:  if I want to execute it after 15 minutes and when I am excecuting after 15minutes I will decide if I want to execute again after 15 minutes not for every 15 minutes of delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `intialDelay` along with `fixedDelay` or `fixedRate`.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000 , initialDelay = 900000) // first execution would be after 900000 ms or 15 minutes
```

See relevant docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#initialDelay--)

Comment: What if I want to execute it after 15 minutes and when I am excecuting after 15minutes I will decide if I want to execute again after 15 minutes not for every 15 minutes of delay..

Comment: out-of-the-box spring `@Scheduled` won't be any help in this case. You need to explore using [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: also consider either updating your question with the scenario or ask a fresh question; as my answer covers the scenario you mentioned in current question.